# Как стилизовать атрибут title?

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте всем. Надо, чтобы при наведении на элемент, допустим, `<button></button>` выскакивала подсказка. Я знаю, что есть аттрибут title, но у него простое окошко былого цвета с рамочкой. Как это окошко можно стилизовать через css? Искал в Яндексе, не нашёл... Искал по такому запросу: "Как стилизовать атрибут title"?

Comment: ищите tooltip'ы и popover'ы

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Никак, нужно отдельно делать всплывающую подсказку. Посмотрите здесь: [Всплывающие подсказки, построенные только на CSS](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=2&id=664).

Answer (score 6):

С помощью CSS стилизованного тултипа можно добиться псевдоклассами [:hover](http://htmlbook.ru/css/hover) и [:after](http://htmlbook.ru/css/after).

[Вот](http://jsfiddle.net/cCveN/) пример.

Answer (score 5):

[@Angus123](/users/3537/angus123),  как правильно заметил [@Spectre](/users/3159/spectre) - для отображения содержимого title браузер использует функции Операционной Системы и  соответственно это нельзя контролировать (за исключением содержимого `title`) но можно создать title-подобное окно средствами html/css `кстати его стиль так-же в таком случае будет кросс-платформенным`.

Answer (score 5):

Рекомендую плагин [jQuery tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/), довольно обширные возможности стилизации